# Is there a consensus among Christian scholars or apologists as to which Biblical prophecies have been fulfilled?

Tags: history, prophecy, apologetics, inspiration, biblical-scholarship

Questions such as [Biblical Prophecy and Fulfillment](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/7209/50422) and [Which prophecies have definitely been fulfilled?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/3339/50422) have already been asked in the past, but they have been closed due to their wording that promotes opinion-based answers.
Since I don't want my question to fall into the same trap, I would like to know instead **if there is any consensus among Christian scholars and apologists** with regards to which Biblical prophecies are most likely examples of actual fulfilled prophecies, thereby providing the best evidence for the divine inspiration of the Bible.

Which Biblical prophecies are believed to have been fulfilled by most Christian scholars / apologists? Among those, which ones are considered to be the most remarkable?

Comment: There are some where I am sure there is a high level of consensus they have been fulfilled (ones re Messiah, destruction of 2nd Temple). But your final question is different - which are *most remarkable*. Can you clarify if the question is about which prophecies are most remarkable, or simple where there is broad consensus.

Comment: @OneGodtheFather - good point, last paragraph amended accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**There are too many prophecies that were fulfilled in the coming and resurrection of Christ that are generally agreed by most scholars to numerate without writing a book.** However to facilitate a sketch of an overview I would first call attention to a nice summary of a [LIST OF OLD TESTAMENT PASSAGES MESSIANICALLY APPLIED IN ANCIENT RABBINIC WRITINGS](https://ccel.org/ccel/edersheim/lifetimes/lifetimes.xi.ix.html) as a sort of handover, if you will, of ancient scholars that in many ways match modern Christian scholars, though often in the weirdest and obscure ways, due to the limited understanding Jews had prior to Christ.

Probably the quickest summary of those prophecies fulfilled with near unanimous Christian agreement are **any Old Testament prophecy referred to in the New Testament**. But the ancient thought of prophecy was not limited to individual statements, but also **Bible Prophetic Themes**, such as the animal sacrifices, the developing genealogical line of the coming Messiah, eventually promised through David, the wide-angled complete overhaul of the covenant, like a second Moses, a second deliverance from Egypt, etc.

Regarding the remarkable instances, there are a few ideas that come to mind: **(1) Christ humanity and divinity revealed, dying as a King, the (2) Outpouring of the Holy Spirit at Pentecost, (3) that through faith in Christ Abraham became a 'father of many nations' (4) that sin was destroyed on the cross and (5) that the meaning of the ceremonial practices, especially the day of atonement, were fulfilled.**

I would like to comment on each. **Christ as a God-Man was not fully expected** but nearly so. As is shown in the gospels, the disciples were expecting a militant Messiah that would make all other nations become subject to Israel. It was only in Christ's actual appearance of a God-Man who came to die, that clarity and meaning, acting as a kind of decryption key, could all the old prophecies now be clearly understood. Previously as you can see in the Rabbinical views, they had a vague idea of what the bible foretold, but once Christ came the mysteries were unlocked and the vague ideas  became certainty and are preached throughout acts and the epistles.

Two of many samples that could be numerated:

> ```
>   He said to me, “You are my son; 
>      today I have become your father. 
>   8 Ask me, 
>      and I will make the nations your inheritance, 
>      the ends of the earth your possession. 
>   9 You will break them with a rod of iron; 
>      you will dash them to pieces like pottery.”
> ```
>
> The New International Version. (2011). (Ps 2:7–9). Grand Rapids, MI:
> Zondervan.
>
> ```
>   2 The people walking in darkness 
>      have seen a great light; 
>      on those living in the land of deep darkness 
>      a light has dawned. 
>   3 You have enlarged the nation 
>      and increased their joy; 
>      they rejoice before you 
>      as people rejoice at the harvest, 
>      as warriors rejoice 
>      when dividing the plunder. 
>   4 For as in the day of Midian’s defeat, 
>      you have shattered 
>      the yoke that burdens them, 
>      the bar across their shoulders, 
>      the rod of their oppressor. 
>   5 Every warrior’s boot used in battle 
>      and every garment rolled in blood 
>      will be destined for burning, 
>      will be fuel for the fire. 
>   6 For to us a child is born, 
>      to us a son is given, 
>      and the government will be on his shoulders. 
>      And he will be called 
>      Wonderful Counselor, Mighty God, 
>      Everlasting Father, Prince of Peace. 
>   7 Of the greatness of his government and peace 
>      there will be no end. 
>      He will reign on David’s throne 
>      and over his kingdom, 
>      establishing and upholding it 
>      with justice and righteousness 
>      from that time on and forever. 
>      The zeal of the LORD Almighty 
>      will accomplish this.
> ```
>
> The New International Version. (2011). (Is 9:2–7). Grand Rapids, MI:
> Zondervan.

The **outpouring of the Holy Spirit answers the prophecies of Joel** the reverse of the Tower of Babel, and many other prophecies.

One of many samples that could be numerated:

> The Day of the LORD
> 28 “And afterward,
> I will pour out my Spirit on all people.
>
> The New International Version. (2011). (Joe 2:28). Grand Rapids, MI:
> Zondervan.

It is **extremely remarkable to me that the Bible foresaw that Gentiles would all take on the religion of the Jews** - so that Abraham becomes a father of those not of his nation. Jesus was obviously the only way this could happen because the world did receive the Jewish religion through him. That he was also according to the correct lineage, with those genetic records destroyed by Rome shortly after, also means there can not  be another Messiah.

Two of many samples that could be numerated:

> 3 Abram fell facedown, and God said to him, 4 “As for me, this is my
> covenant with you: You will be the father of many nations. (Ge
> 17:3–4).
>
> ```
>   23 I will plant her for myself in the land; 
>      I will show my love to the one I called ‘Not my loved one. g’ 
>      I will say to those called ‘Not my people,’ ‘You are my people’; 
>      and they will say, ‘You are my God.’ ”
> ```
>
> The New International Version. (2011). (Ho 2:23). Grand Rapids, MI:
> Zondervan.

That **sin was destroyed and as a Lamb** answers the very first prophecy to Adam and Eve but also the longing of all sinners in all of human history that looked to a Messiah and that sacrificed animals, symbolic of Christ's slain soul bearing God's wrath. This is absolutely remarkable and explains all sacrifices as a practice for all humanity, regardless of how profane and meaningless they may have be in their distortion of the intended sense of Christ's sacrifice for all.

> In the manner of this sacrifice, it is observable that he who brought
> it was to **put his hand on the head of it**: Lev. 1:4, וְסָמַךְ יָדוֹ עַל
> רֹאש הָעֹלָה;—“And put his hands upon the head of the burnt-offering;”
> lay them on, that the beast might seem to bear and sustain them. So
> we, after the Vulgar Latin, “manus suas,” “his hands;” in the
> original, “his hand.” And the Hebrews are divided whether he laid on
> only one hand, his right hand, or both. In chap. 16:21, where the high
> priest was to perform this duty in the name of the people, it is said
> expressly that he shall put שְׁתֵּי יָדָו, “both his hands,” on the
> head of it; whence most conclude that both the hands are here also
> intended. But this seems rather to be an argument unto the contrary;
> for in saying that the high priest (who was to offer for himself as
> well as for the people), in his performance of this work, shall lay on
> “both his hands,” and when a private person did it he shall lay on
> “his hand,” the Holy Ghost seems to intimate a difference between them
> in this action. And this ceremony was observed only when the offering
> was of beasts, not so when it was of fowls or birds. And when the
> season of the sacrifice was stated by God’s prescription for the use
> of the people, the priest was to perform this duty. The meaning of the
> ceremony was, “quod illorum capiti sit,” typically and
> representatively to impose the sin of the offerer on the head of the
> offering; to instruct us in the bearing of our sin by Christ, when,
> through the eternal Spirit, he offered himself unto God.
>
> Owen, J. (1854). An Exposition of the Epistle to the Hebrews. (W. H.
> Goold, Ed.) (Vol. 18, p. 535). Edinburgh: Johnstone and Hunter.

Like I said, this is a very brief sketch and many books can be written on the subject. It's impossible not to miss something big here as Christ truly did fulfill many prophecies in an astounding and remarkable way. In fact, he alone makes sense of all their fragments, into one clear picture like a decryption key.  This is why atheistic so-called Christians, in several modern Universities, make most of their effort to try and prove that the scriptures were not written over such a long period because the weight of these fulfilled prophecies torments their unbelieving minds. Even the enemies of Christianity feel the weight of prophecy. How can one not feel the weight while attempting to use reason in other ways?